# Xcode 13 - "Button" title not disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

After updating to Xcode 13, I face a strange issue, I make a button without title in the storyboard, but it appears with "Button" title in build.

[image: Here's button settings]

And here's what it looks like in storyboard

[image: storyboard button]

But **in build** it looks like this

[image: Button with "Button" title]

Comment: Somebody posted a similar topic yesterday.  What happens if you have one or more white space letters?

Comment: @ElTomato nothing changes, but I found a solution later, need to change a style to default

Comment: Interesting...  El Tomato wonders if that's a bug?

Comment: Yeah I HATE that one. You have to do the same thing if you want to set different images / titles for the various button states. What annoys me is, in what kind of bizarro world situation is the option literally named 'Default' NOT the default?!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I found a solution - need to choose **Default** style.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use icon instead of text. Not only button style **Default** required. You have to check Tint color also because the default is *blue*.

[image: Button tint]

Answer (score -2):

If you want to stick to using a Plain button, try entering a thin space (U+2009) character as the title, which won't consume much space and solves the issue. ([Thanks to @El Tomato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375584/xcode-13-button-title-not-dissapearing/69375632#comment122620809_69375584) for suggesting white space characters)

Here it is for easier copy-pasting: